# 'This' in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, coffeescript, haml, this

What is 'this' in phonegap?  I am working on an app where I have local javascript packed with the app and remote javascript pulled from a server.  I am using coffeescript to generate all the javascript.

Both files are being included in the app's index header, generated through haml as such:

```
%script{:src=>"javascripts/file1.js"}
%script{:src=>"http://192.168.5.205:3000/assets/file2.js"}
```

file1.js.coffee:

```
@myObj1 = property: true
```

file2.js.coffee:

```
@myObj2 = property: true
```

`myObj1` is available globally and can be referenced as just `myObj1`, but `myObj2` is only available via `document.myObj2` and can not be referenced as simply `myObj2`.  What is happening?

Comment: I would imagine your problem is your functions are `=>` not `->`. `@` maintains `this`'s context automatically, for your pure javascript you'll have to do it on your own, ie `var self=this;` then reference `self` instead of `this`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if you say this:

```
@myObj2 = property: true
```

and you have to reference `myObj2` as `document.myObj2` everywhere else, then `this` must be `document` when `file2.js.coffee` is executed. This sort of thing can happen if your code is executed through `$(document).ready()` or similar means (for example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6DFK9/).

If you want something to be global, then you really should be explicit about it and use `window`:

```
# in file1.js.coffee:
window.myObj1 = property: true

# in file2.js.coffee:
window.myObj2 = property: true
```

That way you don't have to worry about the calling context and more importantly, your intent will be explicit and you won't have to puzzle over what `this` is or supposed to be in six months when you're trying to fix bugs. Say what you mean: if you want it global, put it in `window`.